# Create DOORS attribute for section heading

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

**How can I create a DOORS attribute “SectionHeading” to display the section number + title that an object falls under?**

Example (each line here is a DOORS object):

**Section 3.1 XXX Requirements**

Req100  System shall do this… (where this object is under Section 3.1 in DOORS)

**Section 3.1.1 YYY Sub-requirements**

Req234  System shall do this sub-thing….  (where this object is under Section 3.1.1)

Req368  System shall do this other sub-thing… (where this object is also under Section 3.1.1)

**Section 3.1.1.1 ZZZ Sub-requirements**

Req555  System shall do this sub-thing….(where this object is under Section 3.1.1.1)

Req123  System shall do this other sub-thing… (where this object is under Section 3.1.1.1)

Req580  System shall do this other sub-thing… (where this object is under Section 3.1.1.1)

**I want to create an attribute called “SectionHeading” to show**:

Req100, SectionHeading:  “3.1 XXX Requirements”

Req234, SectionHeading:  “3.1.1 YYY Sub-requirements”

Req368, SectionHeading:  “3.1.1 YYY Sub-requirements”

Req555, SectionHeading:  “3.1.1.1 ZZZ Sub-requirements”

Req123, SectionHeading:  “3.1.1.1 ZZZ Sub-requirements”

Req580, SectionHeading:  “3.1.1.1 ZZZ Sub-requirements”

I don’t want to create links within a module from an object to its section header (though this would probably give me what I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a DXL attribute and the code should look like this:

```
Object o = parent(obj)
if(!null o)
{
    obj."NAME_OF_YOUR_ATTRIBUTE" = number(o) " " o."Object Heading" ""
}
```